# удалил некоторые сис файлы в арч линукс

Tags: linux

удалял некоторые файлы в /usr/share. из-за этого перестал запускаться sddm, gdm, да вообще все граф оболочки не запускаются. возможно ли их восстановить?

Comment: Поставь арч заново. И не занимайся больше таким вредительством…